# JavaScript RegExp in replace() not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code

```
var str = "Some text :$0";
var i = 0;

alert(str.replace(new RegExp("\:\$" + i, "g"), 'here'));
```

see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3zyr03h0/).

Why is it not working? If I do it like this `/\:\$:0/g` instead of using the `RegExp` object then it works but I can't use a variable in the pattern that way. Whats wrong?

Comment: `new RegExp(":\\$" + i, "g")`, here https://jsfiddle.net/3zyr03h0/1/

Comment: check the fiddle.

Comment: There *must* be a canonical dupe for this...

Comment: new RegExp(/(\:\$\d*)/,"g") --> https://jsfiddle.net/3zyr03h0/

Comment: @dharmesh: The OP is clear about wanting to target a specific digit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because in string literals, `\` has a special meaning. If you want to actually put a `\` in the *regular expression*, you need to escape it in the string literal:

```
new RegExp("\\:\\$" + i, "g")
```

But `:` has no special meaning in regular expressions, no need to escape it:

```
new RegExp(":\\$" + i, "g")
```

```js
var str = "Some text :$0";
var i = 0;

console.log(str.replace(new RegExp(":\\$" + i, "g"), 'here'));
```