# JavaScript wrong RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

A short question: The following line throws `SyntaxError: nothing to repeat`

```
var regexTel = new RegExp('\+[0-9 ]+');
```

Tools like http://www.regexpal.com/ says that the pattern works fine.

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor. I was having trouble finding it!

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568096/javascript-regexp-in-replace-not-working and a few others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that `\` is special in string literals as well as in regular expressions, so a single `\` in a string literal escapes what follows it at the **string** level; so your regex doesn't actually have that `\` in it at all. (Since `\+` is meaningless in a string literal, it's handled as simpley `+`.) You'd need to escape it at the string level with another backslash:

```
var regexTel = new RegExp('\\+[0-9 ]+');
```

**But**, in JavaScript, you don't have to use strings; use a regex literal instead, so you don't have that problem:

```
var regexTel = /\+[0-9 ]+/;
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is repeat a backslash \, you need to escape it:

```
var regexTel = new RegExp('\\+[0-9 ]+');
```

Comment: It seems to be a phone regex. The first + is the literal one, for prefixes

Comment: Korcholis is right.

Answer (score 0):

As others point out, it's either to add the slashes in the string you pass to the regex:

```
var regexTel = new RegExp('/\+[0-9 ]+/');
```

Or either use the more compact version that removes the use of the `RegExp` object:

```
var regexTel = /\+[0-9 ]+/;
```

Comment: ouch! Could the downvoters hint me why I have a -2?

Answer (score -1):

You have to escape "+" sign. In your regex "\" sign is recognized as a delimiter. 
Go with:

```
var regexTel = new RegExp(/\+[0-9 ]+/);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var regexTel = new RegExp(/\+[0-9 ]+/);
```

Comment: While this may be a valid answer, you are much more likely to help others by explaining what the code does and how it works. Code-only answers tend to receive less positive attention and aren't as useful as other answers.